# How can I pass in a URL from command line into my Gherkin test?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gherkin, webdriver-io

I'm currently running my gherkin tests with a hardcoded url `browser.url("http://www.x.com");`

And I run my tests via `gherkin start [url]`

Is there a way that I can take whatever URL I enter in my command line to start my test and make it take place of the hardcoded url in my `browser.url` call? I am using Selenium-webdriver and docker to execute the tests which are written in Gherkin.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **NO**, unfortunately. As you pointed out, you have a **hardcoded** value in your URL.

But, there should be easy workarounds your problem and with minor changes that can get you to your desired outcome.

**1.** Since you're using **WebdriverIO**, which basically is a Selenium bindings implementation for **NodeJS**, we can actually make use of Nodes build-in objects, in our case the `global object` ***[process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)***.

First, in your test, go ahead and substitute the URL from `browser.url("http://www.x.com");` with a variable, like so: `browser.url(myUrl);`.

Then, declare in your program header that variable: `var myUrl = process.env.URL ?
 process.env.URL : "http://www.x.com"`. This will tell Node: "Look, if you have this process environment variable setup, then return it, else, just give me what you had before (your hardcoded value)".

Finally, when running your test from the command line, just add the variable with your desired value, like so:

```
$ URL="yourUrlHere" gherkin start
```

**2.** Since you're using **WebdriverIO**, I would strongly advise to use their complete tool-suite to leverage a better testing experience. **looks in sadness towards that unused wdio.config.js file**

Thus, I would recommend taking a look at their **[Testrunner](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/gettingstarted.html)** and going through the training sections. If you're keen on using Gherkin, don't worry! WebdriverIO beautifully integrates with **Cucumber** (as well as **Mocha**, or **Jasmine**) which uses Gherkin.

Your issue then would transform into a simple config change via the `wdio.config.js` file.

Let me know if this helps. I can probably muster some other solutions. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm slammed with work currently but will try implementing this as soon as I get a chance and get back to you with my results.

Comment: Okay, so I was able to give this a shot but it's giving me an error of `TypeError: http://www.url.com.url is not a function`. Any thoughts on that? I implemented everything as you stated above and then played around with the `process.env.URL` code by removing the `.URL` from one, then the other, then both of `process.env`. Either had the same error or it just timed out